# Extracting dates from different formats in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change the type of the data type (from `VARCHAR` to `DATE` in PostgreSQL).

Generally the below code works but as you can see there are two date types for `cc_active_date`. Is there a way to emulate try catch in such scenario so that if casting `DD/MM/YYYY` fails then it takes `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`?

```
alter table credit_card.hsbc alter column cc_active_date type date
using to_date(cc_active_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244328/try-catch-equivalent-in-postgres

Comment: Seen that, unable to do it, can u give me a simple syntax for alter column?

Comment: Do you see the part that says "statements" after the BEGIN?  I would imagine that's where your ALTER COLUMN goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE` is very flexible in recognizing the date format, and it already masters your formats. With `SET datestyle` you can control it so that you don't need to distinguish between cases:

```
SET datestyle TO ISO, DMY;
ALTER TABLE credit_card.hsbc ALTER COLUMN cc_active_date type DATE
USING cc_active_date::DATE;
```

An alternative for unsupported formats is an if-condition:

```
ALTER TABLE credit_card.hsbc ALTER COLUMN cc_active_date type DATE
USING TO_DATE(cc_active_date, CASE WHEN cc_active_date ~ '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$' THEN 
    'DD/MM/YYYY' ELSE 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' END);
```

But I would only use something like this if the simpler variant doesn't work.